# eval typeof is undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create JSON object entered into textbox using below code.

**colnames** is array of columns from table  colnames = [DEPTNO,DNAME],

I  am trying to create JSON object dynamically. e.g.

tableInsert.DEPTNO = 100;
tableInsert.DNAME= sales;

but when i run it, it always complain **console.log (eval ("tableInsert."  + col));** is undefined. Any help..

```
  document.getElementById("insercols").onclick = function(){
    var tableInsert ='';
    var colvalue='';
    console.log("cols are " + colnames);
    for (col of colnames){
        colvalue = document.getElementById(col).value;
        eval ("tableInsert." + col + " = " + "typeof "+  colvalue);

        console.log("tableInsert." + col + " = " + "typeof "+  colvalue);
        console.log (eval ("tableInsert."  + col));

    }
}
```

Comment: eval is evil .... and you don't need to **eval** for this

Comment: 1) it's JSON, not jason. 2) There is only one JSON object in JavaScript, and it has methods `parse` and `stringify` on it. You are creating (or rather, should be creating) a plain JS object. 3) You are using `eval`. `eval` is evil. Use `tableInsert[col]` instead. 4) `tableInsert` is a string. Normally you'd set attributes on a plain object `{}`, not on a string `''`.

Comment: @JaromandaX: `eval` does not return `undefined`, it returns whatever the `eval`'d snippet evaluates to. (Well, okay, `eval("void 7")` does return `undefined`.) It is still evil.

Comment: `tableInsert[col]` is easy, but how to do `typeof dynamicVariableName` without `eval`?  Maybe there is a better way to design this. Probably with a lookup table. What values can `colvalue` have?

Comment: Maybe `typeof window[colvalue]`? Still seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: i am returning **colvalue**  from input text box, colvalue = document.getElementById(col).value;

Comment: And what do you type in that box? What is that `typeof` supposed to do anyway?

Comment: as colnames = [DEPTNO,DNAME], so values will be string and number

Comment: @Jaromanda X  i tried  tableInsert[col] = typeof colvalue; its still undefined..

Comment: what do you expect from `eval ("tableInsert." + col + " = " + "typeof "+  colvalue);`  ?

Comment: this is what i am expecting tableInsert.DEPTNO = 100; tableInsert.DNAME= sales, but it never set value..

Comment: @user5310556 - if typeof colvalue returns "undefined" then colvalue is undefined - simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define *tableinsert* as and try again..

```
var tableInsert = {};
tableInsert[col] = typeof colvalue;
```